# DeepSpeed config file not found

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

When running my DeepSpeed training script with the command deepspeed --num_gpus=8 client_entry.py --model_id google/flan-t5-xxl --dataset_path data --epochs 3 --per_device_train_batch_size 8 --per_device_eval_batch_size 8 --generation_max_length 129 --lr 1e-4 --deepspeed dsconfig.json, I encountered an assertion error with the message assert config != None, "DeepSpeed requires --deepspeed_config to specify configuration file". What does this error message mean and how can I resolve i